# SQL - managing character vs. numerical values in a single variable

Tags: sql, casting, case, netezza

Good afternoon.  Perhaps a relatively simple SQL question:

I have a variable.  It represents a count of months within a time series data set.  For each entry, that count will increase incrementally by one when certain conditions are met.  It can have an integer value from 0 to anything really, though it doesn't go much higher than about 160.

However, if there is no data on the count of months, the variable will have a value of "X," and therein lies the problem.  I am trying to put together a query with a WHERE condition that specifies that said variable is greater than or equal to 2 (or 3, or 6 - it's arbitrary).  As you have likely surmised, SQL is unable to parse the "X" value (which, for all intents and purposes, we could define as a very high number).

How, then, might one create a comparative condition for the variable that assigns the "X" value an arbitrarily high number and keeps the respective numerical value for all other situations?  I suspect it involves a "case" function, but I've so far been unable to successfully put anything together.

```
:WHERE a.variable >= 2
```

Thank you for the time and consideration.

Comment: `WHERE a.variable IN (2,3,6)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that will work.  I suppose I could code out the entire set of values from 2 to 160+ within an IN condition, but that doesn't seem particularly practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the X an arbitrary value, you would indeed use a CASE expression.   Here is one that assigns it the value of 10:

```
WHERE
  CAST(CASE
    WHEN a.variable = 'X' THEN '10'
    ELSE a.variable
  END AS int) >= 2
```

Comment: Incidentally, this is exactly what I tried before.  It returns the following error: ERROR:  CASE types "VARCHAR" and "INT4" not matched

Comment: Did you try it with the CAST() function I added in my edit?   It may be necessary to do additional casting within the CASE expression.

Comment: Just tried it with the CAST() function.  It returns the same error.

Comment: Please note that I just edited again to put the 10 in single quotes.   I think that should fix the problem.

Comment: This works.  I was not previously aware of the CAST() function.  This will be very useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a compound statement like:

If the column is a VARCHAR:

```
WHERE CAST(a.variable as INT) >= 2 AND a.variable <> 'X';
```

The bigger question is why you are mixing values in the first place.  Why not make the column specifically a numerical type, and allow it to be NULL for missing values?

Comment: I neither entered the data, nor do I have permission to change it, unfortunately.

Comment: I suspect that this will result in a datatype mismatch error.

Comment: What datatype is the column?

Comment: The problem is you can't cast 'X' as an INT.   So I think you'll still get a conversion error.

Comment: The column is charvar.